# How can I prevent Spring RestTemplate from wrapping my request body in quotes?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

When performing a POST request with Spring's RestTemplate, the request body is wrapped in quotes. Is there a way to avoid that? In my case the request body should be a simple String.

```
  private RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    if (restTemplate == null) {
      restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
      final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
      converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      messageConverters.add(converter);
      restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    }
    return restTemplate;
  }

public void performRequest() {
createRestTemplate().exchange(config.getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST,
          HttpEntity<>("request body String", new HttpHeaders()), ResponseDto.class).getBody();
}
```

The body that is send will be the following:

```
"request body String"
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
request body String
```

Comment: You're using `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`; it's going to produce JSON.

Comment: the response is a json that should be converted to an instance of my ResponseDto class, the request body itself is a simple String

Comment: As stated you are sending json, regardless if it is a simple string. You haven't provided anything as a message converter that handles a simple String. Just create a regular `RestTemplate` (don't mess with the converters) and send plain text, not json.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem! Can you add that as a response so other people with a similiar problem can find the solution easier?